# Soap API Clear data from Data Extension expects object ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to clear data from a DE via the SFMC SOAP API using the example code here:

[**Clearing Data from a Data Extension**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/clearing_data_from_a_data_extension.htm)

The DE object is expecting an Object ID to be set, however I can not find a way to obtain the Object ID for the DE from either the GUI or within code. Passing in the "external reference" from the GUI doesn't seem to work, or is expecting it to be a GUID when in some cases it's a text value, as is the case for the DE I am trying to clear.

I also tried setting the DE object's CustomerEey as the external reference from the GUI but that throws the same error:

> Unable to perform requested operation on DataExtension:

I have also ensured that the API user I created has administrator privileges.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by setting:

```
DE.CustomerKey = "MY DE EXTERNAL REF FROM GUI"
```

instead of `DE.ObjectID = ??` and ensuring that the API user had admin permissions set as well as admin roles which seemed to take a little while to kick in.